# where is emergency message in veins?

Tags: veins

There are two kind of messages in Vanet that are considered as safety messages.Their name are 
1.beacon
2.event driven (emergency message).
I am using omnet++ 5.4.1,veins 4.7.1 and sumo-0.30.0. However veins just has BSM(beacon) and WSA and data that all of them are not emergency message.how can I access to the emergency message in veins?
I need to access to the event driven message.
I read stackoverflow over and over but I did not find that.

Answer (score 1):

As of Veins 4.7.1, only generic message types are included with Veins. You can use them to create a simulation according to your needs. The tutorial example illustrates how to send an event triggered message with a defined transmit power and access category. It might be a good starting point to write your simulation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr sommer.For my thesis I really need to separate beacon and event driven messages from each other and insert them to into different array. for this reason i found startAccidentMsg and stopAccidentMsg which are in TraciMobility and I inserted them into my event driven array and I also inserted bsm which is in BaseWaveAppILayer into my beacon array. However type of startAccidentMsg is msg in veins and msg is split into wsm , bsm and wsa . so Is correct every things i have done?

Comment: Broadly speaking, a beacon is a message that is sent independent of an event happening whereas an event triggered message is one that is only sent when something happens (such as a car braking). How and when messages are sent is defined entirely by you, when you write your application layer.

Comment: I appreciate that you replied me. according to what you said , I should write my event code that messages are triggered via that? according to veins example accident event has been written so after that startAccidentMsg is triggered therefore  can I consider this message as event driven message?